# Overriding removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I am trying to override removeFromSuperview for a custom view i created. The view is intended to contain a UIActivityIndicatorView and i managed to animate its appearance successfully overriding the initWithFrame method. Now i would like to override also its removeFromSuperview adding in it a fade out animation so that from the view controller i can simply call `[self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];` Unfortunately the loadingView is removed without the animation, probably because of the `[super removeFromSuperview];` i need to call when overriding. Here is the code i'm using, is there a way i can fix it?

```
-(void)removeFromSuperview
{
[super removeFromSuperview];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{self.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[self removeFromSuperview];}];
}
```

Comment: `[self removeFromSuperview];` Will this make a infinite loop ???

Comment: No, i think once the view is removed it can't call itself right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `[super removeFromSuperview]` in the completion block for the animation:

```
-(void)removeFromSuperview
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
             animations:^{self.alpha = 0.0;}
             completion:^(BOOL finished){[super removeFromSuperview];}];
```

}

Comment: It was my understanding that when you override a method the first thing to do is to call `[super methodName]`. Am i wrong? Your code perfectly works i just would like to know if what i read about overriding is wrong

Comment: When you override a method, it is generally the case that you will call `[super methodName]` *somewhere* in your implementation. It does not have to be the first line, nor does it have to be called at all. If you have stuff to do before the original implementation should execute, you should do your stuff first; in this case, animating first and then calling the original implementation once your animation is complete.